# Removing contact from Google chat function

Tags: gmail, google-talk

I would like to remove a person from my Gmail chat list and make it so she cannot contact me. She does not appear on my contact list. When hovering over her name on the hangout section it only shows two options. It says I can add to circles or the icon for video chat or message icon. It contains no contact information or e-mail information. She does not appear in my contacts section of my e-mail. She continues to send me messages and I want to block her but do not know how to do this. Help me please because this harassment has to end some day for me.

Comment: You say Gmail chat but then you say "Hangout". Which are you using? (The latter has replaced the former, but Gmail chat is still around and being used by some people.) If you are using Hangouts in Gmail, it's as simple as going to that person's Google+ profile and blocking them. ([Block someone on Google+](https://support.google.com/plus/answer/1047934))

Answer (score 2):

It is really easy to block someone. Refer to the screenshot below.

1. Click on the contact or hover the mouse curser till the basic information window appears.
2. Then in the bottom right corner click on the arrow pointing down. You will see the block option there.

[image]